# c program seg fault not making sense to me (c beginner)

Tags: c, gdb, segmentation-fault

This program compiles but when run outputs a few of the first print statements in the find() method then issues `Segmentation fault:11` when the for loop hits.

So I tried debugging with gdb but could not figure out what the problem is. From what I gathered from gdb the seg fault occurs because of one of the strstr() methods. Also, I noticed that the program shuts-down right before the call to the for loop in the find method. **Why does this program compile but crashes at run-time?**

Here is the output from gdb:

```
Program received signal EXC_BAD_ACCESS, Could not access memory.
Reason: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at address: 0x0000000000000001
0x00007fff8d6469c4 in strstr ()
(gdb)
```

**Thanks for any and all help**. I am a complete beginner practically with  C, but I am trying to learn more.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


int acdc_or_metallica(char *s);
int surfing_or_TV(char *s);
int exo_mustard(char *s);
int arts_theater_or_dining(char *s);

void find(int(*match)(char*));


int NUM_STUFF = 7;
char *STUFF[] = {

"Butthead likes ACDC and TV",
"Beavis likes Metallica and TV",
"Cartman likes to eat",
"Spiderman likes theater and working-out",
"Silver Surfer likes surfing and space",
"GunSword likes mustard and exoskeletons"
"Meatwad likes TV"

};


int main() 
{

find(acdc_or_metallica);
find(surfing_or_TV);
find(exo_mustard);
find(arts_theater_or_dining);

return 0;

}

int acdc_or_metallica(char *s)
{
return strstr(s, "acdc") || strstr(s, "metallica");
}

int surfing_or_TV(char *s)
{
return strstr(s, "surfing") || strstr(s, "TV");
}

int exo_mustard(char *s)
{
return strstr(s, "exoskeleton") && strstr(s, "mustard");
}

int arts_theater_or_dining(char *s)
{
return strstr(s, "arts") || strstr(s, "theater") || strstr(s, "dining");
}

void find(int(*match)(char*))
{
int i;
puts("Search results:");
puts("error below this line...");

puts("-----------------------------------------------");
for (i = 0;i < NUM_STUFF; i++) {
     if (match(STUFF[i])) {
        printf("%s\n", STUFF[i]);       
    }
}
puts("-----------------------------------------------");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 char *STUFF[] = {

"Butthead likes ACDC and TV",
"Beavis likes Metallica and TV",
"Cartman likes to eat",
"Spiderman likes theater and working-out",
"Silver Surfer likes surfing and space",
"GunSword likes mustard and exoskeletons" //<---- , 
"Meatwad likes TV"

};
```

you forgot "," because data is not enough

Comment: This works! Wow, if only gcc said, "missing comma at line n" ^o^

Comment: GCC cannot warn about a missing comma, because it is perfectly valid (and common practice) to put two string literals one after the other (e.g. for code readability, or thru macro expansion).

Comment: compiler won't complain about  write like "first" "second" because it is the correct format to concatenate strings. There is an advantage that can be split into when writing a long string.

Answer (score 4):

You are calling `match` with a `NULL` pointer.

You declare `NUM_STUFF` as 7 (that should be a `#define NUM_STUFF 7` in C), and your `STUFF` array has 5 strings, because of two missing commas

```
"Silver Surfer likes surfing and space", /* you forgot the comma */
"GunSword likes mustard and exoskeletons", /* you forgot the comma */
```

(since you forgot the comma and the next token is a string both lines are concatenated in one string)

<sup>I found that error on Linux by `indent`-ing your code, then compiling it as `gcc -Wall -g u1.c -o u1` and running `gdb u1` to debug it.</sup>

You should have declared

```
#define NUM_STUFF 7
char *STUFF[NUM_STUFF] = {
```

---

In fact, you should add the convention of a `NULL` terminated array.
Then you would have:

```
char *STUFF[] = {
  "Butthead likes ACDC and TV",
  "Beavis likes Metallica and TV",
  "Cartman likes to eat",
  "Spiderman likes theater and working-out",
  "Silver Surfer likes surfing and space",
  "GunSword likes mustard and exoskeletons", 
  "Meatwad likes TV",
  NULL
};
```

<sup>Coding with a terminating `NULL` makes adding new sentences much easier. No need to define or change `NUM_STUFF` in that case.</sup>

Then your main loop would be

```
for (i = 0; STUFF[i] != NULL; i++)
```

---

A stylistic hint: I find

```
void find(int(*match)(char*));
```

quite difficult to read. I personally prefer declaring a `typedef` for the signature of potentially pointed functions, i.e. I prefer coding

```
typedef int matchfun_t (char*);
void find (matchfun_t*);
```

Comment: I tried this but it still did not work. Thank-you though for your time and effort though.

Comment: What does not work? I found the two missing commas as the other answer!

Comment: Hmm I will have to try your solution too I guess with ALL the commas because I only corrected the comma error on one line. Hold please...

Comment: Still having some probs with this solution... you defined the array in one code block initialized to a certain size and in the following code block it is not initialized to any size but initialized with string values

Comment: Yes, because I have provided *two* alternative solutions (with small code excerpts, not a complete homework) .... and explanations about them

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch yes this works, but only when I leave the size of the STUFF[] unset to any specific size. Sorry for the confusion. I should of read your response much more carefully. This solution is much more involved then the other person's but it does work. 1000 thank-yous! :D